# parameter estimation with samples drawn from multiple negative binomial distribution with shared parameter

Tags: estimation, negative-binomial-distribution, fitting

I have $N$ samples, where each sample $Y_i$ is drawn from a negative binomial distribution 
$$Y_i | \ell_i, \alpha, \beta \sim \text{NB}(\alpha, \frac{\ell_i}{\beta + \ell_i}), \quad i=1,\dots, N$$ where $\ell_i$ is known.

Here we are using the $\text{NB}(r, p)$ notation, i.e., $\alpha$ is number of failures until the experiment is stopped, and $\frac{\ell_i}{\beta+\ell_i}$ is  success probability in each experiment.

Is there any way to estimate $\alpha, \beta$? I am thinking about writing down the joint likelihood, but still not sure if it will work. Is  there a name for this statisitical problem?

Comment: There are many different parameterizations of the Negative Binomial distribution (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)). So, I think it would be helpful if you formulate how you parameterize the model.

Comment: Google 'sums of negative binomial random variables' and see if you find something useful. Depending on what the symbols in your question mean (which you should explain), that might be helpful. // For textbook-style problems we ask you to show what you have already tried, say why you need help to finish.

Comment: @baruuum Thanks for the reminder, I am using the $\text{NB}(r, p)$ notation. Also edit the description.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the comment! i googled this, but the related ones are for the same $p$ and different $r$. It seems to me that fitting for sum of NB distribution with same $r$ and different $p$ is a non-trivial one.